# Using Nerdbank to use the height in a beta tag only on non public release branches

Tags: .net, versioning

I have a package project that i would like to be versioned in the following way.

- Set a base version in version.json, say 1.0.
- Every build from a feature branch i would like to produce a package with the following version format: 1.0-beta{height}.
- Every build from master/main I would like the version to be 1.0.

Thus giving me the following workflow:

- New feature branch created and version increased to 1.1.
- Feature branch builds produce the following packages: 1.1-beta0001, 1.1-beta0002, 1.1beta0003
- Once this feature is squash merged into master the resulting package has the version 1.1

I understand I could achieve this by adding and removing the beta tag from the version property but I am after a setup that wouldn't need me to edit the version file unless I am starting a new feature.